# How to get the bluetooth devices as a list?

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth

I am trying to get my bonded bluetooth devices but I can get it as a long string instead of list.

This is my code:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
ArrayList<String> listview = 
new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(pairedDevices.toString()));
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, listview));
```

I am getting something like this: `[00:23:7F:1c, f0:09:f1:b4:b0]`. And its all in one line.
How can I change it to be in a list and not all in one line?

Also, how can I get the friendly names of the devices and not these numbers?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you implemented that when click on item of the list connects to the paired device automatically?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You should change your code as below:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
   s.add(bt.getName());

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list, s));
```

Comment: yea!!!  Thanks!!!  only need to add that i changed List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>(); to ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();  it works great now.

Comment: have the same error after your update.
did the same change i did before and it works now.
this was the error it gave me befor my fix:
The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>

Comment: @waqaslam Is that possible when click on item of that list connect to the device?

Comment: The implementation for list item click listener totally depends on you. You may definitely extend `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to make Bluetooth connection to the device shown in list. Use `listView.setOnItemClickListener` to provide your custom click listener.

Answer (score 51):

**Find** list of **Nearby Bluetooth** Devices:

Find Screenshot for the same.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.i("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
            }
        }
    };
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.bluetoothdemo.MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Manifest** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.bluetoothdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Note:**

Please make sure that you ask Location permission to your user and turn GPS On.

**Reason:** From Android 6.0 you need Location permission for Bluetooth Discovery.

**More reference:**

1. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth
2. https://getlief.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360007600233-Why-does-Android-require-Location-Permissions-for-Bluetooth-

**Done**

Comment: @DavidBalas, Glad to help you.

Comment: Does it connect to a paired device clicked?

Comment: @Skizo, no, it would not.

Comment: Do you know how can I connect it with a click? I mean if I have a list with all of my paired devices do you know how to connect it with 1 click?

Comment: I am trying this code.It is provide all **paired** devices. How can I get **ReadyToPair** device?Is there any way to achieve this thing?

Comment: Thanks for the complete example.

Comment: Is there a reason why the same device appears more than once in the list?

Comment: you need to add 2 more permissions 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: @SruitA.Suk You don't need both of these permissions. You can ask any one of these. If you want to work on approximate location then you should go for 'ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION' else 'ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'.

Comment: @HirenPatel This worked for me but I have one question. I have one device which is scanned using bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery() but not with scanner.startScan(callBack) method. What could be the reason?

Comment: can uh tell me whats this 0C:60:70 and soo on below every devices is this mac address of other devices if yes how can i access our own mac address of bluetooth ??

Comment: @Sunny To get your own Bluetooth MAC address use the below code.
private static final String SECURE_SETTINGS_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS = "bluetooth_address";
String macAddress = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), SECURE_SETTINGS_BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS);

Comment: BroadcastReceiver's onReceive is not triggered any ideas why?

Answer (score 10):

I tried the below code,

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/bluetoothstate" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/listpaireddevices" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="List Paired Devices" 
    android:enabled="false"
    /> 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/bluetoothstate" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
```

**ListPairedDevicesActivity.java**

```
import java.util.Set;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothClass;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListPairedDevicesActivity extends ListActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  ArrayAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter 
    = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

  BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter 
   = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
  Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices 
   = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

  if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
      for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
       String deviceBTName = device.getName();
       String deviceBTMajorClass 
        = getBTMajorDeviceClass(device
          .getBluetoothClass()
          .getMajorDeviceClass());
       btArrayAdapter.add(deviceBTName + "\n" 
         + deviceBTMajorClass);
      }
  }
  setListAdapter(btArrayAdapter);

 }

 private String getBTMajorDeviceClass(int major){
  switch(major){ 
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.AUDIO_VIDEO:
   return "AUDIO_VIDEO";
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.COMPUTER:
   return "COMPUTER";
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.HEALTH:
   return "HEALTH";
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.IMAGING:
   return "IMAGING"; 
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.MISC:
   return "MISC";
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.NETWORKING:
   return "NETWORKING"; 
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PERIPHERAL:
   return "PERIPHERAL";
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.PHONE:
   return "PHONE";
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.TOY:
   return "TOY";
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.UNCATEGORIZED:
   return "UNCATEGORIZED";
  case BluetoothClass.Device.Major.WEARABLE:
   return "AUDIO_VIDEO";
  default: return "unknown!";
  }
 }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

     Intent intent = new Intent();
     setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
     finish();
 }

}
```

**AndroidBluetooth.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidBluetooth extends Activity {

 private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
 private static final int REQUEST_PAIRED_DEVICE = 2;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 Button btnListPairedDevices;
 TextView stateBluetooth;
 BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnListPairedDevices = (Button)findViewById(R.id.listpaireddevices);

        stateBluetooth = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bluetoothstate);
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        CheckBlueToothState();

        btnListPairedDevices.setOnClickListener(btnListPairedDevicesOnClickListener);
    }

    private void CheckBlueToothState(){
     if (bluetoothAdapter == null){
         stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth NOT support");
        }else{
         if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
          if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
           stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is currently in device discovery process.");
          }else{
           stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is Enabled.");
           btnListPairedDevices.setEnabled(true);
          }
         }else{
          stateBluetooth.setText("Bluetooth is NOT Enabled!");
          Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
             startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
         }
        }
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener btnListPairedDevicesOnClickListener
    = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setClass(AndroidBluetooth.this, ListPairedDevicesActivity.class);
   startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PAIRED_DEVICE); 
  }};

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
   CheckBlueToothState();
  }if (requestCode == REQUEST_PAIRED_DEVICE){
   if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

   }
  } 
 }   
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.test.AndroidBluetooth"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".AndroidBluetooth"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <activity android:name=".ListPairedDevicesActivity" 
      android:label="AndroidBluetooth: List of Paired Devices"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Does it connect to the paired device with a click?

Answer (score 4):

```
package com.sekurtrack.myapplication;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView listView;
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.devicesList);



        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BA.startDiscovery();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

       /* BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        pairedDevices = BA.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) list.add(bt.getName());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Showing Paired Devices",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);*/

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                Log.i("BT1", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 2):

In this code you just need to call this in your button click.

```
private void list_paired_Devices() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        ArrayList<String> devices = new ArrayList<>();
        for (BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
            devices.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress());
        }
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(bluetooth.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, devices);
        emp.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way to do it in Kotlin:

*BluetoothActivity.kt*

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class BluetoothActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private var mBTArrayAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>? = null
private var mBTAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
private var mPairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = null

private var mListPairedDevicesBtn: Button? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth)

    mBTArrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
    mBTAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

    mListPairedDevicesBtn = findViewById<View>(R.id.paired_btn) as Button

    mListPairedDevicesBtn!!.setOnClickListener { listPairedDevices() }

}

private fun listPairedDevices() {
    mBTArrayAdapter?.clear()
    mPairedDevices = mBTAdapter?.bondedDevices
    if (mBTAdapter?.isEnabled == true) {
        for (device in mPairedDevices!!) mBTArrayAdapter?.add(device.name + "\n" + device.address)
    } else Toast.makeText(applicationContext,
        "Please Switch On The Bluetooth First",
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

}

*The list view:*

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/paired_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Paired Devices"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

Please tell me if it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it ***inside a fragment*** ...

```
    val bluetoothManager = this.activity?.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
    val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
    val pairedButton = view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.pairedButton)

pairedButton.setOnClickListener {

        if (bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled == true) {

            fun hasPermissions(context: Context, vararg permissions: String): Boolean =
                permissions.all {
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        context,
                        it
                    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                }

            val permissionAll = 1
            val permissions = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT,
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
                )

            } else {

                TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < S")
            }

            if (!hasPermissions(requireContext(), *permissions)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    (activity as MainActivity),
                    permissions,
                    permissionAll
                )
            }
                val pairedDevices: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices
                val pairedList = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.pairedDevTextView)
                pairedList.text = null
                pairedDevices?.forEach { device ->
                    // use 'name' or 'alias' (for edited name) 
                    val deviceName = device.alias
                    val deviceHardwareAddress = device.address // MAC address
                    pairedList.append("\nDevice: $deviceName\nMAC: $deviceHardwareAddress\n")
                }

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(context,"Bluetooth Not Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        }

}
```