# Android bluetooth connect check mac addresses

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to compare the MAC address from a paired device to make sure its one of two known addresses in the app.
I am using the following to get the device

```
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address1);
        mmDevice = device;
    }
```

So what I want to do is something like

```
if(foundMacAddress == address1){
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address1);
}else{
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address2);
}
```

However I am uncertain as to how I can retrieve and compare the MAC address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I could loop through the paired devices, and check the address that way:

```
      BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        String conn = null;
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
        {
            String theAddress = device.getAddress();

            if(theAddress == address1) {
                conn = address1;
            }else{
                conn = address2;
            }
            Log.d("CONNECTION: ",conn);

        }

        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(conn);
        mmDevice = device;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the methods : **.getBluetoothClass() , getMajorDeviceClass()** on the **BluetoothDevice** object, which can be gained from the pairedDevices, in your code. The rest is just string comparison.
Also, this may help you : [How to get the bluetooth devices as a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795424/how-to-get-the-bluetooth-devices-as-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

You can check the activity in the on onActivityResultfunction to find the **MAC address** like this

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
            // When DeviceListActivity returns with a device to connect
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Get the device MAC address
                 String add = data.getExtras()
                                     .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                address= add.toString();

                 // Get the BluetoothDevice object
                BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);

            }
            break; 
}
}
```