# How to get list of all bluetooth bonded devices in android?

Tags: android

How to use Bluetooth Adapter to get name of all bonded devices, i need a proper working code, hope someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the bluetooth devices as a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795424/how-to-get-the-bluetooth-devices-as-a-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure to add these permissions to your app manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"></uses-permission>
```

Now do:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

 if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
   // device doesn't support bluetooth
 }
 else {

   // bluetooth is off, ask user to on it.
   if(!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
       Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
       startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);
   }

   // Do whatever you want to do with your bluetoothAdapter
   Set<BluetoothDevice> all_devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if (all_devices.size() > 0) {
        for (BluetoothDevice currentDevice : all_devices) {
            log.i("Device Name " + currentDevice.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

Full example:

```
public class PairedDeviceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private ListView listView;
  private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<>();

private void getBluetoothPairedDevices(final ArrayList<String> deviceList, final ListView listView){
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "This device not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableAdapter = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableAdapter, 0);
        }
        Set<BluetoothDevice> all_devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (all_devices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice currentDevice : all_devices) {
                deviceList.add("Device Name: "+currentDevice.getName() + "\nDevice Address: " + currentDevice.getAddress());
                listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplication(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceList));
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paired_device);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    getBluetoothPairedDevices(mDeviceList,listView);
 }
}
```

at xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PairedDeviceActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```