# Listen button click of the connected bluetooth device from android application

Tags: android, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth device which has a single button to take a photo using connected android device.

In my application, I can control which device has been connected. But, I need more.

I just wonder that Is it possible to listen click of bluetooth device button from my android application? If it is, at that case, I can use this bluetooth device to my purpose.

Do I need some hack for my bluetooth device ?

Comment: Can you post what you have so far?

Comment: This is simple application that gets bluetooth devices list http://stackoverflow.com/a/10795529/4606266. I just want to listen click of the button of the bluetooth device.

Comment: It would be good to know more information about the Bluetooth device with the button. Have you connected to the device with a generic Bluetooth Low Energy scanning and exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile)?

Comment: Each BT device has its "brain" and you need to know how to works before use it. I think you need to get some specification about Communication with it.

Comment: @ziLk Have you tried seeing the events sent to the device in [`getevent`](https://source.android.com/devices/input/getevent)?

Comment: @Zoso Sorry I really don't remember what I did at that time.

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be an API specification of your Bluetooth device - the list of signals it can send. It can work either like server or client and we can connect to it via `BluetoothSocket` classes and listen to its events. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#kotlin) it is described in more detail.

There is the second option though. If this is some cheap Chinese clicker to make photos from distance it will work in a relatively easier way. Usually, those devices are recognized as remote keyboards. This means you can override the `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` method of your `View`/`Activity`, check which `keyCode` is sent from the device, and handle it accordingly.

In the second case, after the connection is established you won't need any additional Bluetooth-related code changes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the BT device is communicating. But many devices use Gatt communication. So you can do the following to listen for an event:

```
        val btManager = view.getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        val connectedDevices = btManager.getConnectedDevices(GATT)

            connectedDevices.forEach {
                listen(it)
         }


private fun listen(dev: BluetoothDevice) {
    gatt_l = dev.connectGatt(view, false, object : BluetoothGattCallback() {

        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int, newState: Int) {
                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED)
                       gatt?.discoverServices() //on connection, discover services of the BT device that it is offering.
                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
            }
            override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
                super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
                gatt?.services?.forEach { service ->
                    if (service.uuid.toString() == DESIRED_SERVICE) // DESIRED_SERVICE that u r interested in. Initially u will have to go through every service to get ur event.
                      service.characteristics.forEach { // each service has characterstics, u need to listen to all of these to find ur event.
                        if (it.uuid.toString() == DESIRED_CHARAC_UUID) {
                            gatt.readCharacteristic(it)
                            gatt.setCharacteristicNotification(it, true)
                            return@forEach
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onCharacteristicChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?) {
      //When the button on device is tapped, u should get the event here.
                characteristic?.value?.let { data ->
    //this "data" should be the event u want to listen. YOUR LOGIC.
                       }
                super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic)
            }
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicRead(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?, status: Int) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status)
        }
    }, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
}
```