# My bluetooth app is not working properly and work only after opening my bluetooth setting activity

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection, android-bluetooth

I am developing an app which can discover all local bluetooth supported devices if bluetooth is on. But I am in a problem and which is as follow:
When I am running my app and wait for available devices it does not show any device which is on , but when I navigate to bluetooth setting activity(in-built phone activity)
then it shows all local available devices there as well as in my app when I returned back. Please help me. I want to discover all devices by staying on my app and want to see a list of those devices.

I have took permission of BLUETOOTH,BLUETOOTH ADMIN,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

Here is my main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "bluetooth";
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private Button mBTEnableButton;
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
private TextView mShowDevices;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBTEnableButton = findViewById(R.id.enable_bt_button);
    mShowDevices = findViewById(R.id.show_connected_devices);
    mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressbar);


    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    mReceiver = new BlueToothReceiver();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
    intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);


    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    mBTEnableButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);

                bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            }
        }
    });


}

private class BlueToothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("bluetooth", "onReceive");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceAddress = device.getAddress();
            mShowDevices.setText("action : " + action + "\n device name: " + deviceName + "\ndevice address : " + deviceAddress);
            Log.d("bluetooth", "action : " + action + "\n device name: " + deviceName + "\ndevice address : " + deviceAddress);
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Log.d(TAG, "discovery start: ");
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Log.d(TAG, "discovery finish: ");
        }

    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31293094/7511614 this link might help you

Comment: you have called startDiscovery() method when button clicked. have you tried on button click

Comment: write the code to make you device discoverable. your device is not discoverable to others. Opening BT settings makes it discoverable as per android behavior